# Multiple Forms with common JS validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm a newbie to Javascript and jQuery. All I got was this JS function to validate my form. I've got some common fields in both the forms. Instead of calling to different function to validate to different form I want a single JS function to validate all the common fields in both the forms. FYI Both the forms are in different Pages.

**JS**

```
function check1(){
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["type"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Type");
        return false;
    }

function check2(){
    var x = document.forms["form2"]["type"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Type");
        return false;
    }
```

**HTML**

***form1***

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return check1()">
<input type="text" name="type" id="type">
</form>
```

***form2***

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return check2()">
<inout type="text" name="type" id="type">
</form>
```

Thanks in Advance. Please bear me I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a common function for both forms:
(i.e. instead of check1 and check2, use check).

```
function check(){
    var frm = document.forms["form1"] || document.forms["form2"];
    var x = frm["type"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Type");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```